# How to use memento pattern with undo functionality

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a problem using the memento and the command pattern simultaneously. I fully understand the memento pattern is used to save the state of my object on execute before **executing** the change on the object so that I can return back to the initial object in on **unexecute**, but the memento pattern is always saving the same reference of the object when I set the state of it in the memento, do I need to clone the object before creating a memento and setting it too it?

Here's what I have:

```
public class Memento
{
    MyObject myObject;

    public MyObject getState()
    {
        return myObject;
    }

    public void setState(MyObject myObject)
    {
        this.myObject = myObject;
    }
}
```

Command:

```
public class ZoomCommand extends Command
{
    Image image;
    Memento memento

    public InsertCharacterCommand(Image image)
    {
        //instantiate 
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override public void execute()
    {
        //create Memento before executing
        memento = new Memento();
        // set the initial zoom level of the image before executing
        memento.setState(image);
        //set new state
        image.zoomIn(image.getZoom() + 1);
    }

    @Override public void unExecute()
    {
        // redo go back to initial state of image before zoom, but image has the same zoom level
        this.image = memento.getState();
    }
}
```

Image has the same same zoom level in unExecute too, how can I fix this?

Comment: `image` is a reference type, is it not?  Are you familiar with *pass by reference* and *pass by value*?

Comment: Yes reference type, I'm not really familiar :/

Comment: When you pass your `image` to your memento object, you're not passing the actual object to it; you're passing a *reference.*  So when you change your `image`, that change is reflected in the memento as well (everything is pointing to the same `image` object).

Comment: Is it a viable solution for your unExecute to perform an inverse algorithm? In other words `image.zoomIn(image.getZoom() - 1)`. Or must you use momento for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to clone the object.

As usual, the examples found on the internet are rather anemic, but [Refactoring Guru](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/memento/java/example) has a workable example.  Their code for loading and saving the object looks like this:

```
public String backup() {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream b= new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream o= new ObjectOutputStream(b);
        o.writeObject(this.allShapes);
        o.close();
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(b.toByteArray());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return "";
    }
}

public void restore(String state) {
    try {
        byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode(state);
        ObjectInputStream o = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
        this.allShapes = (CompoundShape) o.readObject();
        o.close();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.print("ClassNotFoundException occurred.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.print("IOException occurred.");
    }
}
```

Notice that it doesn't deal in references.  Rather, it provides a scheme for saving out and restoring the entire object's state.  Essentially it is a **deep copy** of the Java object.

Comment: Unexecute read gives back the copied object, so my update doesn't work at all

Comment: As I stated before, this isn't production-ready code; it's just an illustration.  You need to figure out how to deep-clone an object so that you can restore the original object.  Have a look at serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Ok I'm trying my best!